# EditText typed text is below the line and not showing correctly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

See what I am getting

[image]

I have written 15 in the Field. The same is happening with all the 4 `EditTexts` here. I don't know why?

Here is the xml code I am using. It is a simple `TableLayout`. I tried changing the width and `maxlines` but nothing worked.

**Please note the problem is only when the keyboard comes up for the input. When I press back button and keyboard is gone it shows the input correctly.**

```
                    <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewHenna"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/service_column_size"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="2dp"
                    android:text="Henna"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />


                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTextHennaQty"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/column_qty_width"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:digits="123456789"
                    android:hint="Qty"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />


                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTextHennaRate"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/column_qty_width"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:digits="1234567890"
                    android:hint="Rate"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">


                <TextView
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="2dp"
                    android:text="Other"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />


                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTextOtherQty"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:digits="123456789"
                    android:hint="Qty"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="2"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />


                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTextOtherRate"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:digits="1234567890"
                    android:hint="Rate"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />

            </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>
```

Anyone faced this issue? Then please tell how to resolve it.

Comment: share your whole layout with question

Comment: Layout is very big. And it is inside a TableRow. I have updated it.

Comment: u need to share whole layout file, with the properties value

Comment: I updated the layout check it please.

Comment: check in table row have you given any padding or not

Comment: No padding. Should I add some padding?

Comment: @BelalKhan try to add margins and spacing. and aslo check below ans

Comment: Hi plz also put ur dimen file here. so we can solve ur problem easily

Comment: @NileshRathod I tried adding padding and margin but it is same.

Comment: @BelalKhan **`android:layout_width="@dimen/column_qty_width"`** try with some static width in your editext

Comment: @NileshRathod Its not dynamic the value is 100dp, here.

Comment: what is your parent layout of xml

Comment: It is LinearLayout

Comment: @BelalKhan can u please send me your whole layout

Comment: Your email or something where I can send?

Comment: @BelalKhan send me a email please you can find it from my profile

Comment: @BelalKhan did you solved your issue..?

Comment: I sent you the code on your email @NileshRathod

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

```
<TableLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewHenna"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="2dp"
            android:text="Henna"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextHennaQty"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:digits="123456789"
            android:hint="Qty"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextHennaRate"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:digits="1234567890"
            android:hint="Rate"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="2dp"
            android:text="Other"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextOtherQty"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:digits="123456789"
            android:hint="Qty"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="2"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextOtherRate"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:digits="1234567890"
            android:hint="Rate"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

May this works for you.

Comment: accept my answer if it was what helped you. Thank you.

Comment: It worked but, it ruined my alignment. But again when I am puting a width, it goes back to the same problem. Any Idea?

Comment: please can you provide me the specific width?

Comment: Thank you.. I played with weight a little.. and it is now good.

Answer (score 2):

### Its all about margins and spacing.

You have provided only the edittexts code but not of other contents.
Try playing around a little with margins and you will come up with a right numbers to put in there.Try changing the hight or pick a new phone layout that has higer resolution, for adapting that in low resolution you need to find and apply a new style with different margins, so try adding more layouts.
The edittext is getting less space to show its contents.
Hope it helps.

Comment: For lower resolution please decrease the margins and paddings. You can try the constraint layouts auto detect features. Try experimenting with a higher resolution phone and please let us know if that persists. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewHenna"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="2dp"
        android:text="Henna"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:textColor="#000000" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextHennaQty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:digits="123456789"
        android:hint="Qty"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="#000000" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextHennaRate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:digits="1234567890"
        android:hint="Rate"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="2dp"
        android:text="Other"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:textColor="#000000" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextOtherQty"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:digits="123456789"
        android:hint="Qty"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="2"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="#000000" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextOtherRate"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:digits="1234567890"
        android:hint="Rate"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

</TableRow>
```